# Smallest sigma algebra that makes our functions measurable

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose that we have measure spaces $(X_i, \mathcal{X_i})$ for $i \in \mathbb{N}$ and $(Y,\mathcal{Y})$. Consider functions $f_i : X_i \to Y$. Then, can we find the smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $Y$ that makes $f_i$ measurable ?

So far, I can only see that there is a largest $\sigma$-algebra on $Y$ with that property but I cannot figure out how we can prove that there is a smallest one. Also I can see the analogous result for functions $f_i : Y \to X_i$, i.e. to find the smallest $\sigma$ algebra on $Y$ that makes $f_i$ measurable.

Comment: Let the $\sigma$-algebra consist of $\emptyset$ and $Y$, then all functions map into $Y$ will be measurable.

Answer (score 2):

The smallest possible sigma-algebra, $\{\emptyset,Y\}$, makes $f_i$ measurable.